# Repeat/Clone a <tr> element using jQuery's clone() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to clone a template of a  which will be populated with data and then inserted into a table.  I'm currently able to use the same .clone() function with other elements on the same page but jQuery refuses to see and clone the  template (I'm guessing because its not a block element).

Here is the template:

```
<tr id="search_result_temp" class="template">
<td class="logo">
    <img class="logo" />
</td>
<td class="ratings">
    <p id="rating"></p>
</td>
<td class="programs"></td>
<td class="actions">
    <button id="request_info">Request Info</button>
    <button id="save_school">Save</button>
</td>
<td class="compare"></td>
</tr>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
for(var index in results){
        var result = results[index];
        $result_listing = $("#search_result_temp").clone().removeClass('template').attr('id', result.key);
        $search_results.append($result_listing);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should never use a `for...in` loop to iterate over an Array.

Comment: @Nick Craver - it is perfectly ok to use forr..in to iterate over array

Comment: Is the template a part of the document-tree?

Comment: Yes it exists within the rest of the DOM if that's what you're asking.  It is not within any other table.  Its parent element would be <body> since its only a template

Comment: What is the result that you are getting?  And what is $search_results? A little more context might be useful.

Comment: Is it possible that `$("#search_result_temp")` has child elements that have own ids, which you are not reassigning new values when cloning their parent?

Comment: @Ender - jQuery refuses to see $("#search_result_temp") at all as a selector so there is no output.  $search results is defined as: $search_results = $("table.search_results");

Comment: @Lucho - Yes it does have child elements with their own ids such as <p id='rating'>.  I'll play around with those elements to see if it makes a difference.  Why would that affect the cloning?  Also how do you highlight code in the comments?  Thanks.

Comment: To remove/edit the child ids you could try to `...clone().find("*").remove_or_change_or_do_smt_else_with_ids(...)...` on the clone and then operate on them.
To add code use `

Comment: @Justin - Is your template row inside of a table, or just sitting on its own?

Comment: On its own.  That was the problem.  Just posted the answer.

Comment: @Lucho - no it's not, there are many reasons now to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript/3010848#3010848

Comment: @Nick counting is just not the right way to iterate through arrays or list or any collection.
IMHO messing up with Array is not a good idea as well.

Comment: @Lucho - I don't even....you're saying you should never use a `for` loop?  Also don't confuse **iteration** with **enumeration**, they're not the same.

Comment: @Nick No, I am saying that `for` loop is great for counting (e.g. from 5 to 25), but it is not good to iterate on collection as Arrays or lists or others. AFAIK visiting each element of Array one after another is called iterating, not counting :-)

Comment: @Lucho - In an array you should use a `for` loop, to **iterate**, a `for...in` loop is for **enumerating** an object, they're not the same.  For example the indexes in an array aren't guaranteed to be in order (and they aren't in order in IE).  Use a `for..in` loop if you want, but don't say I didn't warn you, any JS expect will tell you it's a bad idea for this and the fact other properties will be in the mix.

Comment: @Nick and @Lucho - The argument in question is an object literal which I believe satisfies both of your opinions.  Lucho, I agree a for loop is for counting but when you're iterating through an array that's exactly what you're doing, counting from 0 to (array.length - 1). Nick, how would numerical indexes in an array not be in order?  The values themselves might not be in order but are you saying the indexes don't go 0, 1, 2, 3... in IE ?

Comment: @Justin - that's exactly what I'm saying, that's why you don't *enumerate* with a `for in` loop.  For an object this is fine, for an Array, it's not.  For an example of what I mean about IE, test this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/fqgAh/

Comment: @Nick Yes, I agree about the IE6 poor behavior. It is safer to use `for`. (IE 7 and 8 are doing the same as IE6... that's insane!!!)

Comment: @Lucho: The enumeration order of objects using `for...in` is specified as being implementation specific, meaning it can be anything. What IE does is no more wrong than what any other browser does. The other problem with using `for...in` for an array is that if `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` has been augmented then you'll get those properties showing up when you use `for...in`.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  The root problem was that .innerHTML will not work with table fragments.  Full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer.  The clone() function works fine when the template `<tr>` is encapsulated within `<table>` and `<div>` elements.  As stated below .innerHTML (which jQuery uses in clone()) does not work with table fragments.  That means jQuery will not clone a `<tr>` if it is a root element (whose parent element is `<body>`).  Therefore, the template should look like this(of course with an appropriate id on the `<div>` to be selected by jQuery):

```
<div>
<table>
<tr id="search_result_temp" class="template">
<td class="logo">
    <img class="logo" />
</td>
<td class="ratings">
    <p id="rating"></p>
</td>
<td class="programs"></td>
<td class="actions">
    <button id="request_info">Request Info</button>
    <button id="save_school">Save</button>
</td>
<td class="compare"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to know why you have to do it this way, it is due to browser limitations in setting table fragments with `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var index in results){
        var result = results[index];
        $result_listing = $("#search_result_temp").clone().removeClass('template').attr('id', result.key);
        $search_results.append($result_listing);
    }
```

correct me if I'm wrong, but why do you need to

```
var result = results[index];
```

index is already a single element of results

Comment: Not in javascript, index is just the index(label)

Comment: @Dr.Molle ... no kidding, it doesn't work like other languages collections? How interesting. Then why not `for(i=0;i<results.count;i++)` ? Or is that the shorthand version of?

Comment: In javascript the for loop iterates through the 'keys' of the object.  So index refers to the key not the value. @drachenstern - Those loops have the same effect

Comment: Its really not the same. use `for(i=0;i<arrArray.length;i++)` for arrays, and `for(var index in objObject)` for all objects except arrays. The second  way could also return other members if used onto an array, for example **length**, that's the hook.

Comment: Example: `Array.prototype.foo='bar';var arr=[1,2,3];for(var k in arr){alert(k);}`

Comment: @Dr.Molle - That difference is good to know.  Thanks.  'results' is an object literal as opposed to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can wrap the template in a hidden DIV and access the content via jQueries HTML method. On a side note, you might bump heads cloning several items with the same ID. Try use a class approach and add an identifier (Try the new HMTL5 data-* tag attribute).